# How to move both objects which has same point, at the same time in JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

// Created an arrow providing two points.

```
var A = board.create('point', [4.0, 2.0]);
var B = board.create('point', [1.0, 1.0]);
board.create('arrow', [A, B]);
```

// Created a line providing two points.

```
var C = board.create('point', [4.0, 2.0]);
var D = board.create('point', [6.0, 2.0]);
board.create('line', [C, D]);
```

Now both point A and C are same. When I move it, only C gets moved as it was created at last. Is there any chance of moving both objects(arrow & line) together when the common point(A,C) is moved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the possibility to glue the two points `A` and `C` together.  To be precise, one can set `C` to be a "glider" on `A`.

```
var A = board.create('point', [4.0, 2.0]);
var B = board.create('point', [1.0, 1.0]);
board.create('arrow', [A, B]);

var C = board.create('point', [4.0, 2.0]);
var D = board.create('point', [6.0, 2.0]);
board.create('line', [C, D]);

C.makeGlider(A).setProperty({fixed: true});
board.update();
```

It is necessary to set `fixed:true` for `C`. Otherwise `C` would get the focus when dragging. But dragging a glider which lives on a point makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Also is there a way to separate it again? something like removeGlider.

Comment: Yes, to unbind the point C just call `C.free(); C.setProperty({fixed: false});`. In version 0.99.3 the method `free` is not yet chainable.